# Errors when sourcing ~/.bashrc

Tags: bash, arch-linux, manjaro

I recently was looking to create alias for different commands. I found out that I had to add the alias to the ~/.bashrc, and then if I wanted to actually have the changes in my actual session, source the file.

The source resulted in some errors that I dont really know how to solve. The errors are the following:

```
/home/educpf/.bashrc:type:64: bad option: -P
/home/educpf/.bashrc:105: command not found: shopt
/home/educpf/.bashrc:107: command not found: shopt
/home/educpf/.bashrc:112: command not found: shopt
```

The lines with the error are this:

> if type -P dircolors >/dev/null ; then

> shopt -s checkwinsize

> shopt -s expand_aliases

> shopt -s histappend

Its weird because I did not make any changes to this file so I would assume that everything worked as supposed, but I guess not. Is this normal to happen, what should I change? Thanks for all the feedback! :)

Comment: I assume you are not using `bash` but `zsh`.

Comment: If you source `.bashrc` and your current shell does not understand `type -P` or `shopt`, that shell is not Bash.  Those commands are built-in to Bash. Bash's `type` builtin understands the `-P` option.

Comment: Okk. Now I feel stupid. I searched for creating alias and found that I had to alter the bashrc file. Because it existed I assumed that I was using bash.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` should show you, which shell you are currently using. Now google for what is the equivalent to `.bashrc` for that shell.

Comment: @treuss That will most likely show you what the login shell was, which may differ from the _current_ shell. You may want to look at the output of `ps -p "$$"` instead. And reading the shell's manual would arguably be more informative than Googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages suggest you are not running the `bash` shell.  I would guess that you are possibly using the `zsh` shell, whose built-in `type` utility does not have a `-P` option like the same utility in `bash`.  Shells other than `bash` will also lack the `shopt` utility.  I don't know what the default login shell of Manjaro is today, but there appears to exist a variant of Manjaro called [*Awesome Community Edition*](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Awesome_Community_Edition/en), which uses the `zsh` shell by default.

Given the `bash` shell's ubiquity in the Linux world, it's not strange that a tutorial (or whatever it may have been) on how to add aliases would describe `bash` shell by default.  And it's not even strange that you have `bash` initialisation files lying around, either from a previous life or put there by the distribution to support users that may want to change their login shell from the default.

To add aliases in the `zsh` shell, put them into your `~/.zshrc` file (or in `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc` if the variable `ZDOTDIR` is defined), or in a file sourced from that file.  This file corresponds to the `bash` shell's `~/.bashrc` file, i.e. it's a dot-script that is sourced when an interactive shell is started.

Luckily, the syntax for defining aliases in `zsh` is the same as in `bash`, at least for basic usage.